# How to enable NTP module CentOS 7?

Tags: configuration, centos7, time-synchronization, ntpd

I have one server running CentOS 7

to install ntp module I followed the below steps:

```
yum install -y ntp
systemctl start ntpd
systemctl enable ntpd
systemctl status ntpd
timedatectl set-timezone America/Mexico_City
```

the service is running, I did not get any error,

```
 systemctl status ntpd
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-04-07 12:43:43 CDT; 50min left
  Process: 2652 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2653 (ntpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntpd.service
           └─2653 /usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp -g

Apr 07 12:43:43 i7box ntpd[2653]: Listen normally on 6 enp3s0 fe80::1cfd:83c7:5a71:977c UDP 123
Apr 07 12:43:43 i7box ntpd[2653]: Listen normally on 7 lo ::1 UDP 123
Apr 07 12:43:43 i7box ntpd[2653]: Listening on routing socket on fd #24 for interface updates
Apr 07 12:43:43 i7box systemd[1]: Started Network Time Service
```

but when I type `timedatectl`

```
 timedatectl
      Local time: Sat 2018-04-07 12:43:45 CDT
  Universal time: Sat 2018-04-07 17:43:45 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2018-04-07 17:43:45
       Time zone: America/Mexico_City (CDT, -0500)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2018-04-01 01:59:59 CST
                  Sun 2018-04-01 03:00:00 CDT
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2018-10-28 01:59:59 CDT
                  Sun 2018-10-28 01:00:00 CST
```

the NTP appears as `NTP enabled: no`, I already opened the port 123/udp

**is there a missing step?**

Comment: It is a bit misleading, it does not mean you have no NTP, it means you have no timesyncd, see the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that really was the problem, the missing step to make `NTP enabled: yes` is:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

**However, your `ntpd` might well be working fine even without:**

You can see more detailed information using `ntpd -q`. It'll list the servers used for synchronization and their status. These servers are configured in `/etc/ntp.conf` and you may change the default

```
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

with pool servers that are near you. Currently [`mx.pool.ntp.org`](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/mx) doesn't have enough servers (you may [join the pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html)):

> There are not enough servers in this zone, so we recommend you use the North America zone (`north-america.pool.ntp.org`):
>
> ```
> server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
> server 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org
> server 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org
> server 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
> ```